# gmaps4rails giving undefined method for city location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rubygems, gmaps4rails

I am using the gmaps4rails gem

I want to test it on one location since it is pulling the contact's location from a hash stored in the database.

I put into my controller:

```
@json = Contact.find_by_email("ted@cottonwoodcomm.com").my_location.to_gmaps4rails
```

I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `to_gmaps4rails' for "Commerce City, CO":String
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is `my_location`?

Comment: my_location outputs the city and state of the Contact. In this case, it's "Commerce City, CO"

Answer (score 0):

`gmaps4rails` requires the `latitude` and `longitude` columns to be added to the model as `float`. If everything is configured right, the method `to_gmaps4rails` will access these columns and the following code should work:

```
@json = Contact.find_by_email("ted@cottonwoodcomm.com").to_gmaps4rails
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. That would usually work if I had some sort of location column. I have a contact_hash column which has a hash of information which one is city location. Hence why the .my_location

Comment: When i do <%= debug @json %> I get --- ! '[]'

Comment: you need `latitude` and `longitude` to find a point on the map.If you want to find a point in the map by the city name, you should use something like geokit[https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails], as I don't think gmaps4rails allows you to do any kind of search.

Comment: And does geokit-rails create a map too?

Comment: nop. it is a utility libraries with methods to find and store locations. You should follow the instructions of gmaps4rails and save the latitude and longitude. If it is not possible, you can use something like the geokit to find the coordinates of a given location, and then display it using the gmaps4rails.